# How to export and restore HSQLDB

Tags: database, export, hsqldb, restore

Does anyone know how to export HSQLDB to `.sql` file or something on a computer and restore on other computer.

Comment: You can just copy the HSQLDB data file(s) (after shutting down HSQLDB of course)

Comment: this should be reopened as it relates to `software tools commonly used by programmers` - HSQLDB is a common tool especially in the java community

Comment: I disagree that this should be reopened.  It doesn't show any effort on the part of the OP.

Answer (score 17):

To get a dump of the hsqldb file using either the embedded or file/server mode.

In an sql tools dialog use:

```
SCRIPT 'c:\path\to\db\db_sql.sql';
```

This will not work with spaces in the path

Please see the [hsqldb docs](http://www.hsqldb.org/web/hsqlDocsFrame.html)

Comment: Could you update the link to the doc to a specific page instead of the homepage? Thanks

Comment: I was trying to update the link, but my edit was rejected. Here is the link to the specific page where SCRIPT command is mentioned: http://www.hsqldb.org/doc/guide/sqlgeneral-chapt.html#N10406. The details you can dig up in http://www.hsqldb.org/doc/guide/management-chapt.html (you need to search for "script statement")

Answer (score 5):

I was trying to export an HSQLDB database, out of an ODB file no less, and found it was very unintuitive. Oddly, I rarely found any tutorials or docs on just a simple export (the kind that is often done with, say, SQLite). I figured the included SqlTool was the right answer, but found nothing obvious ("You might use SCRIPT" is not helpful, sorry). Because this wasn't a database I knew anything about, I couldn't specify schema/table names, nor could I figure out a way to discover those.

In the end, I used an eval copy of RazorSQL (http://razorsql.com). I had to rename the database files to be .script, etc., according to RazorSQL's docs. I set up a Connection Profile that used the "JDBC (HSQLDB embedded)" connection type, selecting the script file that I found in the ODB database. Then I selected DB Tools from the menu, then Export Data, and selected the options that seemed appropriate (CSV file, in my case).

Hope this helps someone else.