# The most easiest way to get the schema from a HSQLDB

Tags: java, database, schema, hsqldb

I want to get the schema from one table from my hsqldb database. At the moment everything is generated with hibernate. Is there a fast and easy solution to get the schema out of the hsqldb?

I appreciate your answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I often use SchemaSpy to generate an html description of a schema including relationship graphs. It uses a JDBC driver to fetch the schema information, so this works with any DB that has one.
http://schemaspy.sourceforge.net

Answer (score 1):

Try [SCRIPT](http://hsqldb.sourceforge.net/doc/guide/ch09.html#script-section).

Same question here: [look here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8059748/how-to-export-and-restore-hsqldb) too.